# CSS - problem with different td heights in one row in editable table

Tags: html, css

First if anyone has a better title for this question can edit. I have a table with three row and three column. The td element in this table has contenteditable attribute , so the user can write something in it. My problem is that when we press enter key in the td to generate new line, the td height increase for one line but other cells of current row stay in primary height. The below figure display my porpuse clearly:

[image]

I have some style for table:

```
table{ 
margin:.5em 0;
display:inline-block;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
table-layout:fixed;
} 

 table tr{
width:100%;
height:auto;
white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:visible;
vertical-align:center;
}

table td{ 
width:100%;
Height:100%;
min-height:2em;
padding:0 .6em;
display:inline-block; 
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Rendered HTML code of table:

```
<table>
<tbody>

<col/>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<col/>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<col/>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Could you privide the html code of table ?

Comment: I have created it with for loop in javascript

Comment: you can copy the rendered HTML from developer tools builtin with browser

Comment: I added rendered HTML code of table

Comment: I don't see the `contenteditable` attribute in your code. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Contenteditable set to TD with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `inline-block` style for `td` elements

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td=>td.contentEditable = true);
```

```css
table{
margin:.5em 0;
width:800px;
/*display:inline-block;*/
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
table-layout:fixed;
}

 table tr{
width:100%;
height:auto;
white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:visible;
vertical-align:center;
}

table td{
/*width:100%;*/
Height:100%;
min-height:2em;
padding:0 .6em;
/*display:inline-block;*/
border:1px solid blue;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<colgroup>
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
</colgroup>
<tbody>


<tr>
<td>afsd</td>
<td>fasdfsa</td>
<td>fasdf</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>fasdfas</td>
<td>fasdfas</td>
<td>fasdfs</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>fasdfs</td>
<td>fasdfa</td>
<td>faasdflkj</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very thanks. It worked so fine. The TD and TR should not be inline-block, but the table can be inline-block.